# How to monitor multiple async image downloads?

Tags: web-access, monitoring, asynchronous-processing, url, scheduledtask

I have a few thousand image urls that I want to ***download asynchronously***, how can I do that while ***monitoring progress***? I'm really asking for 5 things:

- Show dynamic progress in bar
- Downloads must be asynchronous
- Avoid any filename collisions
- Save with correct file extensions (even if not present in url)
- Show list of failed download tasks and why

Here's an example to get started:

```
Monitor[
    URLDownload[
         WebImageSearch["dog", "ImageHyperlinks", MaxItems -> 10], 
         "~/Downloads/"
    ]
]
```

**Updated response to comment**

I don't believe `URLDownloadSubmit` takes a directory, this is the behavior I see (no progress indication):

```
dogs = WebImageSearch["dog", "ImageHyperlinks", MaxItems -> 10]
URLDownloadSubmit[dogs, "~/Downloads", 
 HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskProgress" -> Print, 
   "TaskComplete" -> Print|>, 
 HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"FractionComplete", "ByteCountDownloaded"}]
```

[image]

And the filenames are wrong:

[image]

**Related but not duplicate:**

- [Simple way to monitor a multiple URLDownloadSubmit calls?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177199/simple-way-to-monitor-a-multiple-urldownloadsubmit-calls/177283#177283)
- [How to asynchronously download 100000 urls in an efficient way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25480/how-to-asynchronously-download-100000-urls-in-an-efficient-way)

Comment: You can use HandlerFunctions like so: `URLDownloadSubmit[dogs, "~/Desktop/test", 
 HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskProgress" -> Print, 
   "TaskComplete" -> Print|>, 
 HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"FractionComplete", "ByteCountDownloaded"}]` to print the FractionComplete and ByteCountDownloaded. It's probably a documentation bug that there's no good example of how to do it, but it is mentioned in the usage of URLDownload and URLDownloadSubmit. You can use `ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[frac]]` and `frac = #FractionDownloaded` instead of `Print`.

Comment: @CarlLange thanks, see my update

Comment: I think the message is because "~/Desktop/test" is a file and you are trying to download multiple files to it. Try just "~/Desktop".

Comment: @CarlLange Sorry for the typo, I fixed that but it doesn't look like it's doing anything still. If you could your snippet with a progress bar I'll accept!

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is run `URLDownloadSubmit` once on each URL that you want to download. That will make all those files start to download asynchronously in the background as a result.

When downloading that many images, it's not worth it to keep track of how many bytes have been downloaded of each image. It's better to just count the number of files that have been downloaded so far. That should be granular enough.

Start by getting the URLs:

```
urls = WebImageSearch["dog", "ImageHyperlinks", MaxItems -> 10];
```

Create a progress indicator:

```
i = 0;
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i], {0, Length[urls]}]
```

Let `outputDir` be your output directory. This will start downloading the files:

```
submitURL[url_] := URLDownloadSubmit[
  url,
  FileNameJoin[{outputDir, Last@Information[url, "Path"]}],
  HandlerFunctions -> <|
    "TaskFinished" -> (i++ &)
    |>]

submitURL /@ urls;
```

I used `FileNameJoin[{outputDir, Last@Information[url, "Path"]}]` to keep the original names as requested. However, note that the names may collide with each other. The advantage with UUIDs, as in your screenshot, is that they are always unique.

Comment: When there are missing urls, the progress indicator will never be 100%. How can you add an error handler to count and show the few bad ones?

Comment: If you can add error handler I will accept

Comment: Actually, that collision fix isn't perfect as `FileExtension` returns "" on some urls, is there a better way to inject the uuid into the filename?

Comment: It’s nice that this is abortable but how to handle failures in a nice way?

Comment: @M.R. It depends. Perhaps it would work to just make a list of all the files in that have been downloaded and compare it with the URLs that you tried to download. That way you can make a list of all the files that you failed to download. It would be nice to have some examples of filenames where `FileExtension` fails, perhaps these are especially tricky cases that need special treatmeant not matter how it is done.

Comment: There are a few in that set of urls

Comment: I've added a response to your solution based on your last comment.

Comment: @M.R. You may consider `FileFormat` as an alternative to `FileType`. For the retries, I don't see any downside, compared with the button, to retrying a fixed number of times.

Comment: I'm cleaning up the answer now, it was quite convenient to exchange information in this way but I think that it will be confusing for future visitors.

Comment: Wait by cleaning up did you mean improving on the responses I added or just deleting them?

Comment: @M.R. Removing your responses to make the answer more useful -- less confusing -- to future readers.

Comment: But I improved your answer...

Comment: @M.R. If you want to share what you found, the best way is to post your own answer with pieces of code for problems that you solved. I see the merit in what you wrote, but it is not **my answer**. I would like to keep it short and simple for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Does something like this work for you?

```
With[
    {
    links = WebImageSearch["dog", "ImageHyperlinks", MaxItems->10],
    dir = CreateDirectory[]
    },

    Monitor[
        Table[URLDownload[links[[i]], dir], {i, Length[links]}],
        ProgressIndicator[i / Length[links]]
    ]
]
```

Your original question wasn't clear to me that the downloads were to be asynchronous. Perhaps you can use LocalSubmit for this purpose, e.g.:

```
With[
    {
    links=WebImageSearch["dog","ImageHyperlinks",MaxItems->10],
    dir=CreateDirectory[]
    },

    p=0;
    LocalSubmit[
        Table[
            URLDownload[links[[i]],dir];
            Print[i],
            {i, Length[links]}
        ],
        HandlerFunctions-><|"PrintOutputGenerated" -> Function[p = First @ #PrintOutput]|>,
        HandlerFunctionsKeys->{"PrintOutput"}
    ];
    Dynamic @ ProgressIndicator[p/Length[links]]
]
```

**Response:**

Thanks for updating, here are 100 image urls to test on:

```
urls = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/f691b40d-b12a-41b5-9017-9130bc797fd0"];
```

It seems like it is still downloading synchronously because it takes ~40 seconds, but @C.E.'s only takes ~10 seconds (and speed is the most important factor to me). On the plus side, it seems all 100 images download correctly and the filenames avoid collisions, but the `With` block won't Abort.

Comment: Well not really, because it's not async, and so will be waaay to slow for 10k images.

Comment: Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You solution is too slow because it is sychronous, so do see a way around this?

Comment: @C.E. Your comment doesn't make sense. LocalSubmit uses one kernel for its code, not one kernel per file.

Comment: @C.E. Do you agree that @CarlWoll's solution seems to be 5x slower? Why is that, I thought tasks in `LocalSubmit` would be asynchronous too?

Comment: @M.R. I believe the speed difference is because LocalSubmit starts one kernel to do all of the downloads, while each URLDownloadSubmit uses a new kernel. So, the timing difference is related to the number of kernels you have available.

Comment: @CarlWoll No, that was what I first thought that `LocalSubmit` did. That would have given terrible performance. I assure you that `URLDownloadSubmit` does not use multiple kernels.